# Test DirectX 10 rendering

Tags: directx

I bought a laptop and I was told that installed GPU has problems with DirectX 10 games. I don't have any DirectX 10 games, but I want to check this issue. Is there some tech demo or free game or basically anything that is rendered using DirectX 10 and is free to download?

Comment: Told by whom in what context?  What's the laptop?

Comment: @Shinrai Check that review (the only one) http://www.shopping.hp.com/store/product/product_detail/LH593UA%2523ABA

Comment: The review says DX11, not DX10.

Comment: @Shinrai you are right, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to edit your question adding the laptop/GPU model. In the meanwhile, if it can help, [Lord Of The Rings Online](http://www.lotro.com/) (known also as LOTRO) is free to play MMORPG since some months and it implements DirectX 10 features.

[Age of Conan](http://www.ageofconan.com/) is another MMORPG that implement DirectX 10. There is an unlimited trial available and is going to adopt *"free to play"* model soon.

In addition, it is still available [Tropic Benchmark 1.3](http://unigine.com/products/tropics/), from Unigine. It will immediately give you a feedback if your video card manage DirectX 10 and how many FPS it is able to give you.

Here a useful page that [list many games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_with_DirectX_10_support) with DirectX 10 support.

Besides these, there's also [3DMark Vantage](http://www.3dmark.com/3dmarkvantage/)  - this benchmark program supports DirectX 10.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Both DirectX 10 and 11 worked fine, my fears were unfounded.

Comment: It could still have problems with SOME DX10 games...